# How to use exec() on PHP

Tags: php, exec

I need to execute a php script but without opening the actual script, like for exemple I could put the script in my action section on the form, but I want to execute it in the background, how can i do it with exec()?

Comment: Are you using Windows for your local host or Linux? In Windows, make sure you can run PHP scripts first with a simple script to `<?php echo "Hello"; ?>` or something, then open your command line, navigate to your script directory and type `php myscript.php` to see if it executes.

Comment: im using linux, why?

Comment: For `How to do anything` refer to Google or documentation for that thing `php.net` and if you face any problem using that then you ask here

Comment: Once you can run PHP scripts from your Windows command line then you will need to add in the php first, i.e., `<?php $execPath = './path/to/myscript.php'; $result = exec('php ' . $execPath, $output, $return); ?>`

Comment: I'm not sure how it works on Linux servers but it might be worth trying the php prefix as above.